# add column to csv when exporting numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I'm trying to export a 2d numpy array to csv, while inserting an extra column consisting of a variable from outside the array.

The end goal is to loop through a series of files using the python lasio library, select certain 1d arrays, flatten them to a 2d array, then export to a csv file ready for data loading to a database.

ndarrays might be:

File 1:

```
1.0, 3
1.5, 4
2.0, 56
```

File 2:

```
1.0, 76
1.5, 3
2.0, 45
2.5, 45.6
```

Desired output would be:

```
F1, 1.0, 3
F1, 1.5, 4
F1, 2.0, 56
F2, 1.0, 76
F2, 1.5, 3
F2, 2.0, 45
F2, 2.5, 45.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with numpy as follows,

```
import numpy as np

#Read and label file 1
f1 = np.genfromtxt('./file1.csv',delimiter=',',dtype="string")
label = np.array(["F1"]*f1.shape[0])
f1 = np.insert(f1, 0, label, axis=1)


#Read and label file 2
f2 = np.genfromtxt('./file2.csv',delimiter=',',dtype="string")
label = np.array(["F2"]*f2.shape[0])
f2 = np.insert(f2, 0, label, axis=1)

#Combine and write
fout = np.vstack((f1,f2))
np.savetxt("fout.csv", fout, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
```

Numpy `insert` needs all data in the same format when combining arrays. 
The `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` files contain the arrays in your question and should therefore be read as strings. The labels are generated based on the number of columns and inserted as the first column. The two are then vertically stacked and written out. You need to specify to `savetext` that the output is a string too. The resulting file `fout.csv` is then,

```
F1,1.0, 3
F1,1.5, 4
F1,2.0, 56
F2,1.0, 76
F2,1.5, 3
F2,2.0, 45
F2,2.5, 45.6
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you could add an id column to each file and then concatenate all the arrays. Here is the code for only two arrays:

```
import numpy as np

A1 = np.array([[1.0, 3],
               [1.5, 4],
               [2.0, 56]])
A2 = np.array([[1.0, 76],
               [1.5, 3],
               [2.0, 45],
               [2.5, 45.6]])

A1id = 0
A2id = 1
A1 = np.hstack((A1id*np.ones((A1.shape[0], 1)), A1))
A2 = np.hstack((A2id*np.ones((A2.shape[0], 1)), A2))

result = np.vstack((A1, A2))
```